# How to handle actions on next, prev and view changes in Angular FullCalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I integrated Angular fullCalendar to my Angular project and was able to display events and handle click on them, however I couldn't find anything in the official documentation about how to handle click upon next, prev buttons and on view changes.

My scenario exection is: On next, prev buttons I want to retrieve events related to these days if I'm on timeGrid month and retrieve events related to the whole month if I'm on dayGridMonth.

The calendar declaration in the TS file is as follow:

```
@ViewChild('calendar')
  calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
  private eventToEdit: EventClickArg;


  // other properties
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridDay',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    weekends: false,
    locale: 'fr',
    buttonText: {
      today: 'Aujourd\'hui',
      month: 'Mois',
      day: 'Jour',
      week: 'Semaine'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '22:00:00',
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventBackgroundColor: '#089bab',
    eventBorderColor: '#089bab',
  };
```

The component html is below:

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <full-calendar #calendar
                             [options]='calendarOptions'></full-calendar>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who may concern, I found a property called **datesSet** that I bind to a handler method, it triggers the handler each time a date is changed. This is the new TS file:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    // ... same properties in the question
    datesSet: this.handleDateChanged.bind(this)   };

  handleDateChanged(arg) {
    this.logger.debug('your view is:', this.calendarComponent.getApi().view);
    this.calendarComponent.getApi().removeAllEvents();
    if (this.calendarComponent.getApi().view.type === 'timeGridDay') {
      this.retrieveAllAppointments(this.calendarComponent.getApi().getDate(), this.calendarComponent.getApi().getDate(), null);
    } else if (this.calendarComponent.getApi().view.type === 'dayGridMonth') {
      this.retrieveAllAppointments(arg.start, arg.end, null);

    } else if (this.calendarComponent.getApi().view.type === 'listWeek'){
      this.retrieveAllAppointments(arg.start, arg.end, null);
    }   
}
```

retrieveAllAppointments is the method where I call my Rest API

Comment: This is all entirely unnecessary. fullCalendar will do this all for you. Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed (or if you need more flexibility, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

Comment: @ADyson Hi, the property events accepted by the Angular version doesn't take a function as in the plain javascript library. The links provided are for the Javascript library and don't work for the Angular library in its version 5 which is the one I'm using.

Comment: `the property events accepted by the Angular version doesn't take a function`...this isn't true. The APIs are identical. Only the syntax is different. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular says specifically _"It provides a component that exactly matches the functionality of FullCalendar’s standard API."_. Did you try something which didn't work? Otherwise I don't know how you came to your conclusion. But anyway, if you did, it should be fixable.

Comment: I tried the same code defined in the official documentation by providing some callback functions to the events property but it didn't compile. I'll try to dig more in the library source code to check this path 'cause I agree with you it'll be easier to handle. I'll update my answer if I succeed. Thank you